# How to give conditon while mapping array when it becomes null in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the button to unfollow if the list of users matches any id inside the following array else it should follow button.

terms in my code:
user: its a storage that's store data of logged user
user.following: its an array, when user follow another user that users id is stored here
follower: it contain each users in database

this is i have tried:

```
 {user.following?
          user?.following?.map((val, id) => {

   
            if (val === follower._id) {
             
              return <button className='button fc-button' onClick={() => { handleUnFollow(follower._id) }} key={id}>
                unfollow
              </button>
            } else {
              
              return <button className='button fc-button' onClick={() => { handleFollow(follower._id) }} key={id}>
                follow
              </button>
            }
          })
          : <button className='button fc-button' onClick={() => { handleFollow(follower._id) }} key={id}>
            follow
          </button>}
```

Comment: Can you show us your data file?

Comment: Why would `user.following` be `null`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Array.prototype.includes()** method to check if a particular value is present in an array. If the *user.following* array is not null, you can use **Array.prototype.map()** to loop over the array of followers and return the appropriate button for each follower.

Here is an example of how you can implement this in your code:

```
{user.following && user.following.map((follower, id) => {
if (user.following.includes(follower._id)) {
return <button className='button fc-button' onClick={() => { handleUnFollow(follower._id) }} key={id}>
  unfollow
</button>
} else {
return <button className='button fc-button' onClick={() => { handleFollow(follower._id) }} key={id}>
  follow
</button>
}
})}
```

If the user.following array is null, you can return the "follow" button by adding an else block after the map() method:

```
{user.following && user.following.map((follower, id) => {
if (user.following.includes(follower._id)) {
return <button className='button fc-button' onClick={() => { handleUnFollow(follower._id) }} key={id}>
  unfollow
</button>
} else {
    return <button className='button fc-button' onClick={() => { 
        handleFollow(follower._id) }} key={id}>
        follow
     </button>
     }
}
else {
   return <button className='button fc-button' onClick={() => { 
     handleFollow(follower._id) }} key={id}
   }}
}
```

Comment: else condition after map method is not working.